# Keep table data during Django tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, tdd

I have some tables containing a lot of data (imported from geonames using django-cities: https://github.com/coderholic/django-cities) that I want to preserve in tests (since loading them via fixtures will be very slow)… how can I keep those tables and their data during tests?
I think I have to write a custom TestRunner, but I have no idea about where to start :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible,  here is a way :

1) Define your own test runner look [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/testing/advanced/#defining-a-test-runner) to see how.

2) For your custom test runner look in the [default test runner](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.5.x/django/test/simple.py#L237), you can just copy and past the code and just comment this line : `connection.creation.destroy_test_db(old_name, verbosity)` which is responsible for destroying the test database, and i think you should put the `connection.creation.create_test_db(..)` line in a try except something like this maybe:

```
try:
    # Create the database the first time.
    connection.creation.create_test_db(verbosity, autoclobber=not interactive) 
except ..: # Look at the error that this will raise when create a database that already exist
    # Test database already created.
    pass
```

3) Bound [TEST_RUNNER](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/settings/#test-runner) in setting.py to your test runner.

4) Now run your test like this: ./manage.py test